# Help with ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I'd like to use ScalaTest's Checkers trait to use ScalaCheck from ScalaTest cases.

A simple case I'm playing with is:

```
 test("can create local date UTC from millis") {
     check(localDate.toTimestampUTC.toLocalDateUTC == localDate)
 }
```

I need to create a arbitrary LocalDate, so I tried this:

```
object ArbitraryValues {
    implicit def abc(): Arbitrary[LocalDate] = Arbitrary(Gen.choose(new LocalDate(0L), new LocalDate(Long.MaxValue)))
}
```

It doesn't compile, saying,

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter c:
>   org.scalacheck.Choose[org.joda.time.LocalDate] implicit val abc:
>   Arbitrary[LocalDate] = Arbitrary(Gen.choose(new LocalDate(0L), new
>   LocalDate(Long.MaxValue)))

and

> error: not found: value localDate
>   check(localDate.toTimestampUTC.toLocalDateUTC == localDate)

Answer (score 7):

Ok figured it out through trial and error.  My working code looks like this:

```
object ArbitraryValues {
    implicit val abc: Arbitrary[LocalDate] = Arbitrary(Gen.choose(0L, Long.MaxValue).map(new LocalDate(_)))
}

test("can create local date UTC from millis -and- vice versa") { check((localDate: LocalDate) =>
    localDate.toTimestampUTC.toLocalDateUTC == localDate)
}
```

I had to change the way I was creating the Arbitrary[LocalDate], and then update my syntax for the check.

Comment: Yes, Gen.choose[T](minT: T, maxT: T) requires an implicit object of type Choose[T]. So you could have solved it by implementing Choose[LocalDate], but the solution you came up with is probably cleaner.